# How to avoid `Rest[True]` statements in a set

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a large set of constraints, many of which have such elements as `Rest[True]`. I want to avoid `Rest[True]` elements to be present in the final set of constraints. Here is a minimal example:

```
set = {{{0, Rest[True]}, {}}, {4 (a[2, 1] t[1, 2] + a[3, 1] t[1, 3]) == 
   4 a[2, 1] t[1, 2] + a[2, 4] t[4, 2]&&4 a[3, 1]+t[1, 3]==t[1,2]&&
   0 <= a[3, 1] && 0 <= t[1, 3] && 4 a[3, 1] t[1, 3] t[3, 4] == 4 a[3, 1]  t
   [1, 3] &&4 a[3, 1] t[1, 3] == 5 a[4, 3] t[3, 4], {{0, 
   Rest[True]}, {}}, {{0, Rest[True]}, {}}}}
```

How can I avoid `Rest[True]` elements to occur?

Comment: This `set = set /. Rest[True] -> Sequence[]` will give warning messages because it is puzzled by `Rest[True]` but it will then remove all those and assign the new smaller result to `set`  It might be a more interesting question why you are getting those and how to avoid those. If you wanted to edit your question to show what is likely generating those then perhaps someone could show a way to avoid them in the first place.

Comment: @Bill: I will try to reformulate the question without giving additional code because people will not be interested in the details of how I end up with `Rest[True]`. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure where this comes from, but Rest[True] does not have any meaning, as you know since it gives the error: "Rest::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Rest[True]." So the way to fix this is *not* to generate a meaningless expression and then remove it, but to fix things so that your code does not generate meaningless expressions in the first place\.

Comment: @bill s: I will now edit the post with an example, and this may help to detect the problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Introduced in V10.2 (according to the help for V11.3) we have `Nothing`.  You can eliminate members of a list by replacing them with this, e.g.:

```
set/.HoldPattern[Rest[True]]->Nothing
```

To illustrate the effect...

```
{a, b, c, d, e} /. c -> Nothing
(* {a, b, d, e} *)
```

Comment: I suggest using the rule `HoldPattern[Rest[True]] -> Nothing` to avoid an annoying message from the LHS of the rule.

Comment: @mikado: In fact, I could get rid of the unwanted terms by `Rest[True]->0` but this is not what I wanted. I wanted to totally drop it from the list. I tried `DeleteCases` also but again no success. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @Mikado: Yes, your example does what I want, but in my `Mathematica v. 10.2` , the command `Nothing` does not exist.

Comment: @bill s: If I can find `Table[modelF[wG, i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]` by excluding the cases in which `i=j`, then I will not have `Rest[True]` elements. The question boils down to excluding the cases `i=j` either by `Do` or by `Table`.

Comment: @bill s: Referring to my previous comment, I modified an answer of (Nasser) to produce the matrix where the diagonal cells are deleted by construction. This solves the problem created by `Rest[True]`. Here is the `code`: `Table[If[i != j, m[[i, j]], Sequence @@ {}], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]`